# Not recognised as a name of cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to execute a script to extract current security on the server but I get the following error:
`The term get is not recognised at the name of cmdlet`

The script I’m trying to run is:

`Get-adgroupmember -identity “domain admins” | select name

1. The execution policy is remotesigned
2. Tried to execute using normal user and as an admin

Would you please let me know what I may be missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks like you have a typo (space) in you script. if you only type get on the shell you get: ```get: The term 'get' is not recognized``` maybe you have ```Get -adgroupmember```

Comment: Thank you for your response - I tried it without the space and it seems to be the same issue

Comment: [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74138634/not-recognised-as-a-name-of-cmdlet#comment130897197_74138634) is right. There is either a whitespace character in there (perhaps even one you can't see) or this isn't the line that throws this error. Just retype the command and try again.